# “Ancora” vs “di nuovo”

Tags: word-choice

Simple question. I'm confused about when to use "ancora" vs "di nuovo".

They both mean "again", but there seems to be a slight difference in meaning.

Could someone explain the difference?

Comment: In what context does *ancora* mean *di nuovo*?

Comment: @egreg E.g. *Fallo ancora(=di nuovo) e ti do una sberla*.

Comment: Though I don't have this down, my Italian teacher says there is a difference between ancora and di nuova. I'll ask again and repost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While *di nuovo* means only *again*, *ancora* can have different meanings.

For example it may be translated with *still* when it refers to the continuity of an action/state in time:

> Sono ancora stanco del viaggio. (I'm *still* tired for the trip)

Or it can mean *yet*:

> Non è ancora giunto il momento. (The moment has *yet* to come)

It can even mean *more*:

> Ancora un quarto d'ora e ho finito (One *more* quarter of an hour and I'll finish this).

(Examples taken from [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ancora_res-d49bd28d-000d-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/).)

Comment: So when the two words *do* mean the same thing, they are completely interchangeable?

Comment: @Groky Yes. Whenever you can use *di nuovo* you can also use *ancora*. At least I can't come up with any example where this isn't true.

Comment: So, for instance, could "le scarpe sono ancora in scatola" mean "the shoes are still in the box" or "the shoes are in the box again" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista It can mean both depending on context. Although that "standalone" sentence would more likely be interpreter as the former without any more context.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it may be difficult to get for a non native. 
The main difference is that "ancora" in some cases is used to highlight that something is still happening, so to highlight that something started in the past and is still going on at present (or even future).
"Di nuovo" means instead that something is happening again /anew.
I suggest that you should have a look at these examples:

http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/italienisch-englisch/ancora
http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/italienisch-englisch/di-nuovo

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

As Bakuriu has exhaustively explained, *di nuovo* indicates just the repetition of actions meanwhile ancora (pronounced *ancòra* instead of *àncora*, which mean anchor) alters its meaning depending on the context.

Furthermore, *ancòra* it's widely and variously (and not necessarily grammatically incorrect) employed in dialects along all the peninsula to describe temporal or hypotetical sentences when followed by a verb at its imperative.

Comment: Welcome, Luscinia!

Comment: Could you explain a bit better this dialectal use, adding a source and perhaps some example?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that ancora in the meaning of ‘again’ means actually ‘once again’ while we are using it in phrases we usually use it without ‘once’. If you can replace ‘again’ by ‘once again’, then ‘di nuovo’ is exchangeable. If not, then not.
Hope this serves you !

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, Robert, and thanks for your contribution. It seems to me that, as it is now, this answer is quite confusing. Can you try to explain this with more detail, giving some examples of what you are saying?